# Include revision or tag name on website pages (ASP.NET) when deploying with CruiseControl.net and subversion

Tags: asp.net, svn, deployment, cruisecontrol.net

Is it possible to include the revision number or the name of the tag used for a build on an ASP.NET website when deploying with CruiseControl.net and subversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) for this. By integrating it into your build script, you can do keyword replacement in your source, replacing with things like the current revision number.

You can also make use of the [svn:keywords property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.properties.html) for this. The svn:keywords property works on a file-by-file basis, though, and thus expands to the last revision of the file, as opposed to the last revision of the repository as a whole.

Comment: Thanks for that useful clarification